# jQuery: How to validate date using multiple formats?

Tags: jquery

I would like to validate an input field as being a valid date, but I would like to specify the date format on a case-by-case basis. Something like:

```
<input id="date" type="text" data-validate="true" data-val-date="mm/dd/yyyy">

<input id="date-two" type="text" data-validate="true" data-val-date="dd-mm-yy">
```

My validation looks like:

```
// inputValue is the value of the input
// typeValue is the value of data-val-date

var comp = inputValue.split('/');
var m = parseInt(comp[0], 10);
var d = parseInt(comp[1], 10);
var y = parseInt(comp[2], 10);

var date = new Date(y,m-1,d);

if (date.getFullYear() == y && date.getMonth() + 1 == m && date.getDate() == d) {

    return true; // Passed

else {

    return false; // Error

}
```

This works when the date format is ALWAYS `mm/dd/yy`, but how can I tweak this to use whatever format is passed using the `data-val-date` attribute?

The m,d and y letters will always be the same. I just need to check how many characters each should be (mm or m, yy or yyyy, etc), and I need to see what the separator is (/,-, etc).

Comment: simplest way would be use moment.js which accepts format argument

Comment: `$('input').data('val-date');` would be a good start and implement an `if/else if` chain or a `switch(){}`. Within your logic block you will only have to properly set the first 4 vars and the rest of your code should take care of itself.